# API can't read body request send by flutter http.post

Tags: json, laravel, flutter, api, flutter-hive

I tried to send a json data which is populated from hive database using flutter as mobile app and API using Laravel, but my API keep saying that the request is empty.

This is my flutter http.post

```
Future<void> SendDataBacklog() async {
    var jsonBacklog = jsonEncode(backlogList);

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://109.141.122.292/asmankit-api/api/koko/t1a/input/test'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonBacklog,
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //show your outputs
      Hive.box('asmankit_backlog').clear();
      AlertPostBerhasil(context);
    } else {
      print('Backlog data: $jsonBacklog');
      print("response backlog: " + response.body);
      AlertKoneksiFailed(context);
    }
  }
```

This is my json data

```
[{
    "tanggal_catat": "2022-12-08 21:28:18",
    "id_mesin": "12",
    "hsd": "11",
    "rpm": "11",
    "tekOli": "11",
    "tempMasuk": "11",
    "tempKeluar": "11",
    "tempMesin": "11",
    "r": "11",
    "s": "11",
    "t": "11",
    "kw": "11",
    "hz": "11",
    "volt": "11",
    "cosQ": "11",
    "age": "testing| Backlog"
},
{
    "tanggal_catat": "2022-12-08 23:22:29",
    "id_mesin": "12",
    "hsd": "99",
    "rpm": "99",
    "tekOli": "99",
    "tempMasuk": "99",
    "tempKeluar": "99",
    "tempMesin": "99",
    "r": "99",
    "s": "99",
    "t": "99",
    "kw": "99",
    "hz": "99",
    "volt": "99",
    "cosQ": "99",
    "age": "testing| Backlog"
}
```

This is the request response, which say there is no data passed when call the API

```
response backlog: {"success":false,"message":"Silahkan Isi Data Yang Kosong","data":{"tanggal_catat":["Masukkan Title Post !"],"id_mesin":["Masukkan Title Post !"],"hsd":["Masukkan Content Post !"],"rpm":["Masukkan Content Post !"],"tekOli":["The tek oli field is required."],"tempMasuk":["The temp masuk field is required."],"tempKeluar":["The temp keluar field is required."],"tempMesin":["The temp mesin field is required."],"r":["Masukkan Content Post !"],"s":["Masukkan Content Post !"],"t":["Masukkan Content Post !"],"kw":["Masukkan Content Post !"],"hz":["Masukkan Content Post !"],"volt":["Masukkan Content Post !"],"cosQ":["Masukkan Content Post !"],"kwhProd":["Masukkan Content Post !"],"keterangan":["Masukkan Content Post !"]}}
```

Last is my flutter mode map toJson

```
Map<String, String> toJson() => {
        'tanggal_catat': waktuCatat,
        'id_mesin': idMesin,
        'hsd': hsd,
        'rpm': rpm,
        'tekOli': tekOli,
        'tempMasuk': tempMasuk,
        'tempKeluar': tempKeluar,
        'tempMesin': tempMesin,
        'r': r,
        's': s,
        't': t,
        'kw': kw,
        'hz': hz,
        'volt': volt,
        'cosQ': cosQ,
        'age': keterangan + "| Backlog",
      };
```

Comment: Hmm have you tried passing your data to jsonEncode maybe on you're backend accept differently on json so if that doens't work does also passing the data ? Does you able to log it or print to make sure the data you are passing is not null or empty.

Comment: Might help to provide how you define the route in the backend and how the controller code looks like

Answer (score 0):

The [URL](http://109.141.122.292/asmankit-api/api/koko/t1a/input/test) you gave
is not accessible so I am going with your word that it works.

Now since you say `print("response backlog: " + response.body);` is being hit, that means the if condition of `statuscode = 200` is not true.

In general `POST` requests return a status code of `201` and not `200` when successful. Can you change `200` to `201` and see?